# Visual Studio Code loops in snippets

Tags: coffeescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is there a way how to use loops or conditionals when creating snippets in VS Code? I am trying to create a snippet that will generate a template for JSDoc documentation syntax for a function. Example (I am using coffeescript):

```
myFunction: (param1, param2): ->
  # some code
  return
```

And I would like a snippet that generates:

```
###*
 * @param {} param1
 * @param {} param2
 * @return {}
###
myFunction: (param1, param2): ->
  # some code
  return
```

I am able to create a snippet, that will simply generate:

```
###*
 * @return {}
###
```

using this snippet settings:

```
"JSDocs Template": {
    "prefix": "jsdoc",
    "body": [
        "###*",
        " * @return {}",
        "###"
    ],
    "description": "create template for JSDocs"
}
```

But to achieve want I need, I would have to use a loop to go through the param list and that is where I struggle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I found out that such a behaviour is not possible with snippets only, therefore I have create my own extension [CoffeeScript JSDoc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bambusekd.coffeescript-jsdoc). Feel free to use it and extend it if necessary...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is that possible using snippets. You can achieve this by writing your own extension using VS Code API.

But you can use this extension 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments
to achieve what you trying to achieve in your example.

Update: 
You have to modify this extension script a little bit.

1. Go to C:\Users\%UserProfile%.vscode\extensions\stevencl.adddoccomments-0.0.8\out\
2. Add this additional logic in the 'extension.js' file. 
   [image]

Right now it only works for the ts and js file. Just added the coffeescript language type.

And it works!!!
[image]

Mark it right ans if you agree.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, but it this extension doesn't work with CoffeeScript...

Comment: Check the update, I tested it and works fine with the change.

Comment: well, now it works for coffeescript but it is not generating the correct syntax, which is: `###*` insted of `/**` and `###` instead of  `*/` . I am going to extend this extension or write my own, thanks for your help...

Comment: thanks for your effort, but I ended up creating my own extension, check my answer for details...